# Animated gif showing still instead of spinning

Tags: jquery

The following snippet i am currently using to display animated gif on button click event to display a loading gif till data returns from server but its only displaying a still image not an animated spin whats wrong here

In jquery

```
$("#btnSearch").jqxButton({
    theme: theme,
    width: '80',
    height: '25'
});
$("#btnSearch").bind('click', function () {
    if (lookupSearchValidation()) {
        $(this).toggle();
        $("#loading").show("fast", function () {
            //method to populate the grid
            LoadLookUpSearchGrid();
        });
    }
});
```

in html

```
<img id="loading" src="Images/spinner.gif" alt="" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="button" value="Search" id='btnSearch' />
```

Comment: Does your spinner work when you just display it on the page without any javascript?

Comment: Are you sure the gif is animated? Try to open it with the browser and check if it's animating, otherwise the problem is the gif.

Comment: yes it does i checked it

Comment: What does LoadLookUpSearchGrid do?
Browsers usually don't render the website (including updating animations) while javascript is being interpreted. If this functions does a lot of work, it could be responsible for the still animation

Comment: LoadLookUpSearchGrid method basically does the ajax call to fetch data from server and i think it takes 10-20 sec to do that

Comment: @MofX would you suggest any other alternatives to achieve this

Comment: If it is using ajax and events to process the ajax result, this shouldn't stop the animation.

Comment: Unless it is using jquery with synchronous mode enabled (which is the dumbest feature that library ever implemented…)

Comment: @Dave : the ajax method i am using is below but i have the async attribute to false $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 async: false,
                 cache: false,
                 url: 'AddEditView.aspx/LoadLookUpSearchGrid',
                 data: JSON.stringify({ FilterType: $('select#ddlFilterType').val() , Id: $("#txtId").val() , Name: $("#txtName").val(), SearchText: '', FilterRows: filterGridRows}),
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});

Comment: async false == synchronous. You need to set async to true (which may take some refactoring of your code but is worth it to stop your browser hanging). Making it asynchronous will make you animation work. Never (seriously never) use `async:false`.